# How to use Jquery Ajax to pass variable to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

[image: SQL DAtabase]

[image: Select option]

Hi! I'd like to ask your help. Using jquery-ajax select option function, how can I get the result when row is cross match with column. In the select option image I attached, how do I get the 625 value from my SQL table.(SQL DAtabase.jpg)
if I select 3/4" in the first select option and 36" in the second
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your SQL database image is unavailable.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried in your attempt? Where specifically are you running into a problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First create a web service:

```
<?php

$c1 = $_GET['dropbox1'];
$c2 = $_GET['dropbox2'];

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db_name");

$q = "select `column_name` from `table_name` where `column1`='$c1' AND `column2`='$c2'"; 
$res = mysql_query($q);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

echo $row[0];
```

Now call web service from Form Page

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

$("#option2").on("change", function() {
       var link = "webservice.php?dropbox1=" + document.getElementById("option1").value + "&dropbox2=" + document.getElementById("option2").value;
        $.get(link, function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    document.getElementById("answer").value = data;

});   
        });
    });
    </script>
<body>
<select id="option1"><option>option1</option><option>option1</option><option>option1</option></select>
<select id="option2"><option>option1</option><option>option1</option><option>option1</option></select>
<select id="answer"></select>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: Please change variables and column names accoridng to your script.